# Full specialization of method template from class template

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, template-specialization

I know this subject should be pretty much dated by now, but I'm having a tough time with this specific case.

Straight to the point, this is what I want to do:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    E_1,
    E_2
};

template <MyEnum T>
class MyClass
{
    // method to be fully specialized
    template <typename U>
    void myMethod(U value);
};

// full specialization of method template from class template
// (or is this in fact partial, since I'm leaving T alone?)
template <MyEnum T>
template <>
void MyClass<T>::myMethod<int>(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++03 [$14.7.3/18] says

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, **except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates  are  not  explicitly  specialized  as  well**.

So you need to specialize the enclosing class too.

Something like this would work.

```
template <>
template <>
void MyClass<E_1>::myMethod<int>(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I was just enlightened by your answer. I'm ashamed to notice I always got the "you have to specialize the enclosing class" thing wrong: I thought I had to actually redeclare the whole class, but it just means I'll have to duplicate the methods being specialized.. Right? That's somewhat boring, but it's much better than I thought!

Answer (score 1):

Since you leave T, while specializing only function template, then what you're trying to do would be called partial specialization, because T is still templated and you can use it in your function. But unfortunately, partial template specialization of function (whether be it member function or non-member function) is **not** allowed. So your code would give compilation error.

Either you fully specialize by specializing the class template as well, or you don't at all.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. I just never got my head around the idea of rewriting the whole class when I heard people saying I "had to specialize the whole class". It was just today that I realized they referred to template <> template <>... What a shaaame~